# Should I write these ordinal operations in Cantor normal form?

Tags: ordinals

I want to increment $\omega^2+\omega+n$ by $\omega$

I.e. the operation I require is $f:\{\omega^2\cdot\alpha+\omega\cdot\beta+n\}\times\{\omega\cdot\beta_2\}\mapsto \{\omega^2\cdot\alpha+\omega\cdot(\beta+\beta_2)+n\}$

What's the best way to describe this?  Clearly it's not normal ordinary arithmetic:

> $\omega+(\omega^2+\omega+1)=\omega^2+\omega\cdot2+1$

One obvious way is to simply write both in Cantor normal form and say to pairwise add the coefficients of matching exponents.

Then I want to transform $\omega+1$ to $\omega^2+\omega$ by increasing the exponents of every term.

but again I don't think I can just write $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega$ so all I can come up with is to say shift the coefficients left in Cantor normal form... actually I think in this last case maybe to write $\omega\cdot(\omega+1)$ might be okay.

Comment: $\omega+\omega^2=\omega^2$; recall ordinal addition is non-commutative.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown as I thought

Comment: There is an ordinal calculator here https://sourceforge.net/projects/ord/ I tried it quickly seems fine to practice ordinal arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [natural (or Hessenberg) sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations) of ordinals. In the natural sum, you simply add the coefficients in the Cantor normal form.

Answer (score 4):

Ordinal addition and multiplication are not commutative. Incrementing $\omega^2+\omega+1$ by $\omega$ results in $\omega^2+\omega+1+\omega = \omega^2+\omega+(1+\omega) =\omega^2+\omega+\omega = \omega^2+\omega*2$

$(\omega+1)\omega$ is $\omega$ copies of $\omega+1$. That is not the same thing as $\omega^2+\omega$, which is equal to $\omega(\omega+1)$

Comment: Thank-you. You've answered the 2nd part but for the first part I require a way to write the transformation $f(\omega,\omega^2+\omega+1)=\omega^2+2\omega+1$.  I'm asking if the only way is to say pairwise add corresponding coefficients in Cantor normal form or is there a better wa?.

Comment: @RobertFrost $2\omega=\omega$ thus you can you add $0$.

Comment: As accumulation said $(\omega^2+\omega+1)+(\omega+1)=\omega^2+\omega.2+1$ is what you want.

Comment: Ok I have the noncommutative part but I require a function that gives $f(\omega^2\cdot\alpha+\omega\cdot\beta+n,\omega\cdot\beta_2)=\omega^2\cdot\alpha+\omega\cdot(\beta+\beta_2)+n$ and the question asks whether writing out to pairwise add the coefficients in Cantor normal form is the only way.